# Force SQLite 3.7 to run in legacy mode?

Tags: android, sqlite

My Android app works with SQLite databases.  They are created in SQLite v3.6 (legacy mode) so that they are compatible with all Android devices.  However, a small set of the devices running SQLite v3.7 are auto-promoting the SQLite db's to v3.7, which makes them incompatible with older devices.

Is there a way to tell devices running v3.7 not to upgrade the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PRAGMA legacy_file_format = 1
```

According to the [SQLite website](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_legacy_file_format):

> This pragma sets or queries the value of the legacy_file_format flag.
>   When this flag is on, new SQLite databases are created in a file
>   format that is readable and writable by all versions of SQLite going
>   back to 3.0.0. When the flag is off, new databases are created using
>   the latest file format which might not be readable or writable by
>   versions of SQLite prior to 3.3.0.

Comment: Hmm, yeah.  That implies that a device running 3.7 should not tamper with a 3.6 db, and let it stay a 3.6 db.  The Evo 3-d is just a jerk then.  I wonder if explicitly telling it to leave it as legacy would help.